# how to add pdf header and footer dynamically using hhandoko (play26-scala-pdf) in play framework 2.6

Tags: html, scala, pdf, playframework

I'm using hhandoko (play26-scala-pdf) library for dynamic pdf generation.
The task is to generate a pdf from tabular format data (more than 1000 rows). First, I create an HTML page and generate a pdf from the above library (hhandoko). I need to add a header and footer for pdf (each page).
**How do I add header and footer?**

```
pdfGen
        .toBytes(
          views.html.pdfGenerator("hello", Seq.empty, 33.3,None),
          ""
          ,
          Seq("fonts/opensans-regular.ttf")
    )
```

Comment: I found this anws that works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263416/generating-header-footer-with-flying-saucer-xhtmlrenderer-and-itext